# Jquery Issue About ScrollTop coding

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

```
if($('html, body').scrollTop().val() > 50){
$("#scrolltop").css("display", "block");
};
```

**Those're my codes, but of course don't work.
How can I apply to it with "if" questioning.. ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not quite sure what you mean.

Do you have an element "scrolltop" which you only want to display if the body has scrolled passed 50px?

If so, here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t52HN/4/

Comment: Sorry about that, have updated it to use `$(window).scroll` and tested against all major browsers. (It was only working in Chrome previously)